# how to config nginx location for multi folders

Tags: nginx, single-page-application

how to config nginx location for multi folders use wild rule with regex.
The nginx config sample:

```bash
# TODO how to write wild rule to get same effect as specific rule
# location ~* ^/location-test/(.*)$ {
#   # alias /path/to/static/;
#   try_files $uri $uri/ /location-test/$1/index.html;
# }

location /location-test/spage {
    alias /path/to/static/spage/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /location-test/spage/index.html;
}

location /location-test/web-stu-card {
    alias /path/to/static/web-stu-card/;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /location-test/web-stu-card/index.html;
}
```

The static files tree:

```bash
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── spage
│   ├── css
│   ├── index.html
│   └── js
└── web-stu-card
    ├── css
    ├── index.html
    └── js
```

Comment: Try: `root /path/to/static/; try_files /$1 /$1/ /$1/index.html =404;`

Comment: @RichardSmith not work,  `try_files $uri/$1 $uri/$1/ /$1/index.html =404` could get index.html properly but not css or js files.